# How to count if two elements in an array are pairs?

Tags: python

So this is a HackerRank problem but I gave up and no one has completed it in Python (3).

Here's the problem:

*There is a large pile of socks that must be paired by color. Given an array of integers representing the color of each sock, determine how many pairs of socks with matching colors there are.*

So you are provided number of socks and an array of integers representing socks, it looks as follows:

```
n = 9
ar = [1,2,1,2,2,3,4,2,1]
```

The correct answer is 3 pairs. Notice this is two pairs of 2 and one pair of 1. Here's how I attempted it, any ideas?

```
def sockMerchant(n, ar):
    "Count number of pairs of socks in array"
    pairs = 0
    for i in ar:
        if i == ar[i +1] & (pairs/2 == 0) :
            pairs = pairs + 1 
    print(pairs)
    return
    

sockMerchant(n, ar)
```

It returns 1, which isn't correct.

Comment: `i` is an array element, not index. Why are you using `ar[i+1]`?

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator. The logical operator is `and`.

Comment: The only time when `pairs/2 == 0` is when `pairs == 0`. What's the purpose of that part of the condition?

Comment: Why is `n` passed in the function?

Comment: There's hardly anything in your code that makes sense. It looks like you're only checking for pairs that are adjacent in the list.

Comment: I learned Python last week, apologies folks

Comment: It seems like you barely thought about this, and just put together something that looks kind of like a solution, and now you're expecting us to rewrite it correctly.

Comment: @Barmar damn, I really tried spent a half hour on it but I gotta keep grinding it seems

Comment: @JohnThomas Kudos for spending time on it, but you are missing the fundamentals such as `&` vs `and`. I would read a basic introductory tutorial before attempting to solve problems.

Comment: @Selcuk thanks for that, i've been using DataCamp; any other resources you recommend?

Comment: check the `collection Counter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary mapping colors to counts and then sum the counts as pairs:

```
def sockMerchant(n, ar):
    "Count number of pairs of socks in array"
    colors_to_counts = {}
    for color in ar:
        colors_to_counts.setdefault(color, 0)
        colors_to_counts[color] += 1
    return sum(count // 2 for count in colors_to_counts.values())
```

Your approach doesn't work because, in addition to what the commenters pointed out, you are only checking for consecutive pairs.

Comment: Use `collections.Counter()` instead of your own dictionary code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That would totally work, but I prefer to avoid imports for HackerRank/interview questions because they abstract away too much functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved in one line. Also note that `n` is not needed as it is redundant:

```
sum(ar.count(i) // 2 for i in set(ar))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension and a `Counter`:

```
ar = [1,2,1,2,2,3,4,2,1]
from collections import Counter
a = Counter(ar)
# go through each type of sock and count how many there are (`k`), store how many pairs (`k//2`) and then sum up all of the pairs (`sum`)
return sum([(k//2) for (k,v) in a.items()])
```